# how to display thumbnail from category using getThumbnailUrl() in Magento

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, magento

I have bee trying to make this work but had no luck, Basically I need to display the main menu categories on the content block and I did, but now I need to display the thumbnail categorie next to the category name inside the content block. I created a new custom module inside app/desing/fronend/default/THEME/template/catalog/navigation/category_listing.php   that looks like:

```
<div class="box layered-nav">
    <div class="head">
    </div>
    <div class="border-creator">
      <div class="narrow-by">
          <dl id="narrow-by-list">

         <dd>
         <ol>        
        <?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
            <dt>
             <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($_category)): ?> class="active"<?php endif ?>><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>
             <img src="<?php echo $_category->getThumbnailUrl() ?>" width="100" height="100" style="background:red; height: 100px; width: 100px; display: block" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>" />
             </a> 

            </dt>
        <?php endforeach ?>

       </ol>
      </dd>
      </dl><script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list')</script>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And then I am adding this to app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/model/Categorie.php

```
            public function getThumbnailUrl()
            {
                $url = false;
                if ($image = $this->getThumbnail()) {
                    $url = Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$image;
                }
                return $url;
            }
```

Any ideas why is not pulling and displaying the image? I already added to the category using the admin panel, cleared the cache and refreshed the data, Any ideas?

[image: Magento and Firebug]

Answer (score 5):

Use this below function to display category thumbnail image

```
   public function getThumbnailImageUrl() 
   {
      $url = false;

      if ($image = $this->getThumbnail()) {

         $url = Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$image;
      }
      return $url;
   }
```

Then, using for any category :

$_imageUrl=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getThumbnailImageUrl()

you can get the thumbnail image.

Refer this article 
http://www.douglasradburn.co.uk/getting-category-thumbnail-images-with-magento/

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution working on Magento 1.7.0.2

**Create sub-categories.phtml file**

```
Location: app/design/fronend/YOUR-THEME/default/template/catalog/navigation/sub-categories.phtml
```

Take note of where to pull thumbnail images from. You will need to add an absolute path of your website at `www.yourwebsitenamehere.com` below.

sub-categories.phtml file contents:

```
<div id="categories">
  <?php $_maincategorylisting = $this->getCurrentCategory() ?>
  <?php $_categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories() ?>
  <?php if($_categories->count()): ?>
     <? foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
        <? if($_category->getIsActive()):
           $cur_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
           $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
           $layer->setCurrentCategory($cur_category);
           $catName = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getName();
           if($_imageUrl = !$this->getCurrentCategory()->getThumbnailImageUrl()):
              ?>
              <?php /* Default subcategory jpg if no image exists */ ?>
              <div class="category-box">
                 <div class="category-image-box">
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                       <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/subcategory-default.jpg') ?>">
                    </a>
                 </div>
                 <div>
                    <p>
                       <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"> <?php echo $catName ?></a>
                    </p>
                 </div>
              </div>
           <? endif ?>
           <? if($_imageUrl = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getThumbnailImageUrl()): ?>
           <?php /* Displays the subcategory image */ ?>
           <div class="category-box">
              <div class="category-image-box">

                 <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                    <img src="http://www.yourwebsitenamehere.com/media/catalog/category/<?php echo $_imageUrl ?>">
                 </a>
              </div>
              <div>
                 <p>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"> <?php echo $_category->getName() ?></a>
                 </p>
              </div>
           </div>
        <? endif; endif; ?>
     <? endforeach ?>
     <?php $layer->setCurrentCategory($_maincategorylisting); ?>
   <? endif; ?>
</div>
```

**Create a static block.**
  1. Block Title: Sub Category Listing
  2. Identifier: sub-categories
  3. Content: `{{block type="catalog/navigation" template="catalog/navigation/sub-categories.phtml"}}`

**Create Category.php file**
Copy `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category.php` to  `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category.php`. Once copied, edit file.

Once inside file, look near line 491. Find:

```
public function getImageUrl()
{
    $url = false;
    if ($image = $this->getImage()) {
        $url = Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$image;
    }
    return $url;
}
```

After this paste in:

```
/**
 * Retrieve thumbnail image URL
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getThumbnailImageUrl($fullpath = false)
{

  $url = false;

  if ($image = $this->getThumbnail()) {

      if ($fullpath == true) {
          $url = Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$image;
      } else {
          $url = $image;
     }
  }

  return $url;

}
```

**Backend Magento.**
1. Select Catalog > Manage Categories.
2. Create or edit the main category that will display thumbnails from sub categories.
3. Under Display Settings Tab
4. Display mode: Static block only
5. CMS Block: Sub Category Listing
6. Is Anchor: No
7. Thumbnail Image: Choose your file

If you do not see your edits make sure to flush your Magento cache.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to change app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category.php

It can be done easily through these line of code...try this...Its Works

```
$child= Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId();

$imageSrc = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($child)->getThumbnail();

$ThumbnailUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$imageSrc;

echo "<img src='{$ThumbnailUrl}' />";
```