# Easy Categories Extension Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have installed this extension but images not coming with categories https://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/free-stuff/easy-categories.html

Anyone who has worked on it can help me please?

According to my understanding and after checking url with echo, getThumbnailImg($category) this function not working

```
 <?php foreach ($__subCategories as $category):?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="sub">

                            <a href = "<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrl($category) ?>">
                                <img src=<?php echo Mage::app()->getStore(0)->getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$this->getThumbnailImg($category); ?> width="<?php echo $this->getThumbnailSize(); ?>px" />
                            </a>

                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
```

it is not a permission issue I have checked

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133228/how-to-display-thumbnail-from-category-using-getthumbnailurl-in-magento

Comment: not working i tried everything :(